# Android 6+ Permission concept and Location Strategies

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, locationmanager

How does Google think that this strange concept with the Android 6+ permission work where the user has to accept the permission for the Location strategy. What I mean in detail: The new permission concept should show a grant permission popup to a user in that moment he wants to use a special function within the app. How should this work with `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...)`? The [manual](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) says

> You might want to start listening for location updates as soon as your
>   application starts, or only after users activate a certain feature.

So if I show the permission popup at app startup, this permission concept would be without any sense, since the user has to accept a permission without knowing why. When I execute `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...)` just when he hits the location button, then the location manager is not fast enough to get the proper location as far as I know (it's difficult to test, so I'm not sure).
What is the correct implementation concept for Android 6+ permissions when using Location manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to ask permission to your user for Location at the startup. Since you only need to ask permission only once in per installation, it shouldn't be too annoying. If user allows your permission, you don't need to worry about anything else and user can continue using your app. But if he denies it, it's better to show him a popup dialog explaining why your app needs this permission to continue. If he still denies, you can choose either forcing him to leave the app or limiting the feature you asked for permission earlier.

See this [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)

Comment: I think I will disable the location button when the permission is not granted.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for permission at startup helps you to disable any feature related to the specific permission. If you want, you can ask for permission when you really need it and check for the user response. The three basic methods for do that are:

- `checkSelfPermission` (Determine whether you have been granted a particular permission.)
- `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` (Gets whether you should show UI with rationale for requesting a permission. You should do this only if you do not have the permission and the context in which the permission is requested does not clearly communicate to the user what would be the benefit from granting this permission.)
- `requestPermissions` (Requests permissions to be granted to this application. These permissions must be requested in your manifest.)

Combining these three methods you can create a workflow to handle dynamic request permissions, e.g:

```
public boolean checkPermission(int requestCode, int permissionExplanation, OnRequestPermissionCallback listener, String... permissions) {
        boolean permissionGranted = true;
        for (String permission: permissions) {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                permissionGranted = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!permissionGranted) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            boolean shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = true;
            for (String permission: permissions) {
                if(!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)){
                    shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale) {
                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                ActivityUtils.showAlertInfoMessage(this, getString(permissionExplanation), getString(R.string.dialog_information), v -> {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
                }, false);

            } else {

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You should check for user permission granted in `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback method (Note: this method gets call in the activity because I'm using the three methods from `ActivityCompat` if you want to handle `onRequestPermissionsResult` from a `Fragment` you need to use `FragmentCompat` instead and you fragment has to implements `FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` that contains the abstract method `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`, check out this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html) for more details.

Comment: My question is about handling the complicated Location workflow together with the new permission model, not how to implement permissions in general, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well I give you the whole picture, all you need to do is check first if you have permission before call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(...)` with something similar to the method I posted